Undefined variable $tag?
I started to learn Laravel a couple a days ago but I have error in code somewhere where it says that $tag variable is undefined, my Blade template is below:
@props(['tag','size'=>'base'])
@php
    $classes = "bg-white/10 hover:bg-white/25 rounded-xl font-bold transition-colors duration-300";
    if ($size === 'base') {
        $classes .= " px-5 py-1 text-sm";
    }
    if ($size === 'small') {
        $classes .= " px-3 py-1 text-2xs";
    }
@endphp

<a href="/tags/{{strtolower($tag->name)}}" class="{{ $classes }}">{{$tag->name}}</a>

In the JobController.php:
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Tag;
use App\Models\Job;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreJobRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateJobRequest;

class JobController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $jobs = Job::all()->groupBy('featured');
        return view('jobs.index', [
            'featuredJobs' => $jobs[0],
            'jobs' => $jobs[1],
            'tags' => Tag::all(),
        ]);
    }

}


the $tag is undefined, check what controller is sending to the view, it won't write the ->name

Can you paste your controller class? Seems like you are not passing that variable to the template.

Hi, there is only one controller and that is JobController.php :

Please edit your question with more context. Show jobs.index code

@Mislav Novalić, it's all(), so you will get an collection (array), you need to do a @foreach ($tags as $tag) <a href="/tags/{{strtolower($tag->name)}}" class="{{ $classes }}">{{$tag->name}}</a> @endforeach on the view. If you don't have any tags in DB it will be undefined..

Sorry but this does not help it says that $tags variable i undefined. I do not get it :(

Is all that code in jobs.index, or are you using Blade Components? If you're using a component, show both the jobs/index.blade.php and your blade component file. If it's all in index.blade.php, then you shouldn't be using slots, and you should use a foreach inside of your blade file.

It's saying that $tag is undefined. You have $tags, which is a collection of Tags, but no single $tag variables, unless there's a loop that you're not showing us.

If I delete this line app is working normally but without that tag displayed in index.blade.php

Since you are learning Laravel: instead of partly hardcoding your href, use the route helper :  {{ route('your-named-route', ['param' => $param])}} . In this case, if your route ever changes, you don't need to change any links in the app.

In your JobController, you're retrieving all tags with Tag::all(), but it looks like you're not actually passing the $tags variable to your Blade template when rendering it.
@props(['size' => 'base', 'tags'])

@foreach ($tags as $tag)
<a href="/tags/{{ strtolower($tag->name) }}" class="{{ $classes }}">{{ $tag->name }}</a>
@endforeach


Added tags as a prop in your Blade template.
Used a @foreach loop to iterate over each $tag and generate the links.
Verify that your Tag model is correctly set up and that it has a name attribute


Your are sending value name is tags
public function index()
    {
        $jobs = Job::all()->groupBy('featured');
        return view('jobs.index', [
            'featuredJobs' => $jobs[0],
            'jobs' => $jobs[1],
            'tags' => Tag::all(), //here 
        ]);
    }

But you didn't using same name in views. You can use foreach as well.
<a href="/tags/{{strtolower($tag->name)}}" class="{{ $classes }}">{{$tag->name}}</a>

You can read this document for help
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/views#passing-data-to-views
